# Calculate Number Months between 2 dates DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am doing a rolling 12 month avarage over a specifik sum that are a calculated column if that matter? and my count over 12 month returns 355 day?

My sum column is [Volume]

I have a Calendar Table that are set up accordingly to a hierarchy as picture show below and more,[image]

my code for the rolling avarage is,

```
12M tonnage Avarage = 
            CALCULATE(
                SUM(STOWAGEACTUAL[VolyMton]);
                DATESINPERIOD('Calendar'[DATE]; LASTDATE('Calendar'[DATE]);12;MONTH)
)
/
CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Calendar'[DATE]);
        DATESINPERIOD('Calendar'[DATE];LASTDATE('Calendar'[DATE]);12;MONTH
        ))
```

All my values that i have in my SUM column looks like this,

[image]

And my Rolling AVG abowe calculates to this,

[image]

After some error searching i find that this piece of code,

```
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Calendar'[DATE]);
        DATESINPERIOD('Calendar'[DATE];LASTDATE('Calendar'[DATE]);12;MONTH
        )
```

Gives me a Distinct Count value of 356. And when build my report to look on Days. My Rolling Average does compute correctly.

BUT, this is not what i want since i want this DAX to return 12 and i cant figure out why is doesnt?

Comment: Do you have a month column in your date table?

Comment: @Christoffer yes, I have monthnumber and month name